# VSCode - How to reload all windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I knew `workbench.action.reloadWindow` could reload the current VSCode window, how to reload all windows at once, I searched through the keybindings, but didn't find one.

Some use cases:

1. After upgrading extensions that require reload.
2. VSCode slowed down for no obvious reason, trying to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS, `workbench.action.quit` is assigned to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, use this command to quit the app, then reopen will restore all windows.

On Windows, `workbench.action.quit` has no assigned shortcut, we need to assign it a shortcut, then use it to quit the app, then reopen will restore all windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no any shortcut for this. But you can quit from vscode, this will close all windows, after that reopen vscode, it will open all windows again. And this will be reload all windows.